Where does standard output go when I launch with "externalConsole": false?
I'm running VScode on a Mac. I can run with "externalConsole": true in my launch.json, but if I do, I get this annoying little terminal window that pops up and won't go away unless explicitly dismissed.
So I try false. It looks like the standard output should have three tabs where it could turn up: Output, Debug Console, or Terminal. But in fact I find it in none of those. I see compiler output in Output; I see messages as libraries are loaded in Debug Console, but I don't see my application's standard output anywhere. Is there a way to get it to appear in one of these places?  Surely whatever library loading does, I could do?

Have you changed the drop down option in the Output window to change between the various outputs?

That menu has 20 options and none of them look like the obvious choice.  Suggestions?

Depends on what you're doing - what are you trying to see the output for?

@TimothyG. - trying to see stdout/stderr from my C++ program.

Quoting the docs:

Used only when launching the debuggee. For attach, this parameter does not change the debuggee's behavior.

Windows: [...] When set to false, it will use VS Code's integratedTerminal.
Linux: [...] When set to false, it will use VS Code's integratedTerminal.
macOS: [...] When set to false, the output can be seen in VS Code's debugConsole. Due to limitations within lldb-mi, integratedTerminal support is not available.



It is indeed showing in the debugConsole.  I can't explain why I wasn't finding it there in previous builds.
